# How to count the number of microstates in this example and in general

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle, identical-particles

Suppose we have $3$ energy levels $E_1,E_2,E_3$, that we need to fill up with $3$ electrons. Each of these Energy levels can be filled with two electrons - **spin up** and **spin down**.

How does one calculate the total number of possibilities in this case - the total number of possible **micro-states**.
For example, let there be two electrons in $E_1$ and one electron in $E_2$. It is obvious that the two electrons that are paired, must have opposite spins, due to the exclusion principle. As for the third electron, it could either be spin up or spin down. My question is, do we consider these separate microstates, or are these the same microstate ?

In a certain source, they mentioned that there are $7$ possible microstates, for the above system. $1$ in which all electrons are in separate levels, and $6$ in which there are $2$ electrons in one level, and $1$ in another level. In total there are $7$ possible microstates for $3$ electrons in $3$ energy levels.

However, this seems extremely wrong to me. For example, they mentioned that there is one state where we have $1$ electron per energy level. However, they have not considered the spin of the individual electrons in the energy levels. For example, the system could be $up,up,up$ or $up,down,up$ or something else. However, all of these should be different microstates, according to me.

According to me, there are $20$ possible microstates. This is how I did the sum :

$$W_i = \Pi_i \space \frac{g_i!}{n_i!(g_i-n_i)!}$$

This is the total statistical weight for a particular configuration. There can be $7$ possible configurations, but $6$ of them would be $2$-fold degenerate and $1$ of them would be $8$-fold degenerate due to spin. So I add the possible weight of all these configurations and get the total number of microstates.

$$\Omega = \sum_i W_i$$

Another simple way to do this would have been to realize, that the Energy levels are all $2$ fold degenerate due to spin ( angular momentum degeneracy is ignored in the problem ). Since there are $3$ possible energy levels, we can say that there are $6$ possible energy states. Since electrons are fermions, they can each occupy one particular state. Then, the total number of microstates can be given by: $$\Omega = \binom{6}{3} =20$$

What I think the source did, was to count the number of possible configurations, or rather, the number of macrostates. However, each of these configurations corresponds to a number of microstates. For example, in the case where we had one electron per energy level, and thus $3$ electrons in $3$ energy levels, we have $8$ possible microstates, because of the spin of the electron. They didn't factor that, in their reasoning. That seems wrong to me.

Can anyone tell me, if I'm correct in saying that different spin orientations must be considered as different microstates, or do we just consider the configuration here, as they did. WHich one is the correct answer to the above question, please verify that for me.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it seems like the spins would not "count" as extra micro states because the possibilities are constrained.  For two electrons on a level you can't have "up, up", "down down", or "up, down."  It's only the latter.  The spin quantum number is what enables you to have two electrons in a single shell+angular momentum level; otherwise there could only be one per level.

Comment: Plus I think when an electron is by itself it does not have a definitive up or down spin.  It has has a probability of being measured as either (in that direction).  In the paired case, the up/down direction is still not well defined until measured, but the two electrons are entagled and guaranteed to be in opposite spin states.   I'm not a QM expert, but I think I am recalling that aspect right

Comment: @RC_23 for the paired case, I don't care about if it is up state or down state, but for an unpaired electron, spin degeneracy should be considered because it would be a different microstate. It would the same microstate, it should be 20, I guess.

Comment: I don't think the single unpaired electron state has a degeneracy of 2, because there are not two distinguishable states.   That state has a 50/50 chance of being measured as spin up or spin down. There are not distinct "unpaired up" and "unpaired down" states. There is only "unpaired."  So the possible arrangements of 3 electrons in the energy levels (E1, E2, E3) are: (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 0), (2, 0, 1), (0, 2, 1), (0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 2), (1, 2, 0) or 7 possibilities.

Comment: An interesting case might be if these were energy states in an atom, whose nucleus had a spin state of its own.  Then an unpaired electron level *could* distinguish between "spin aligned with nuclear spin" and "spin not aligned. "  But that is a different scenario

Comment: @RC_23 yeah, but I think this atomic concept is more general. For example, take 2 unpaired electrons in 2 energy levels. That is one single configuration. However, there are four possible wavefunctions, $1$ singlet and $3$ triplets. So, we can say there are $4$ microstates, corresponding to the configuration. In that particular example, the spin of the unpaired electron, does matter. I agree that if they were in the same level, it wouldn't matter.